# Python Jinja2 post

Tags: python

I just want to check if my elif statement is correct to check for content composed entirely of white-spaces. Thanks.

```
 def post(self):
            wall_name = self.request.get('wall_name',DEFAULT_WALL)
            comment_container = CommentContainer(parent = wall_key(wall_name))
            comment_container.name = self.request.get('name')
            comment_container.content = self.request.get('content')
            if comment_container.content == '':
                self.redirect("/error")
            elif comment_container.content == str.isspace:
                self.redirect("/error")
            else:
                comment_container.put()
                self.redirect('/#comment_section')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `isspace()` function is an *instance* function and also a class function -- meaning you can call it on an existing string or by passing it an argument.

For example:

```
>>> 'foo' == str.isspace
False
>>> 'foo' == str.isspace()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'isspace' of 'str' object needs an argument
>>> str.isspace('  ')
True
```

The first line there *appears* to work correctly because `str.isspace` does indeed not equal the string 'foo', but this is because 'foo' is a string and `str.isspace` is a function. We never called `isspace()`!

```
>>> str.isspace
<method 'isspace' of 'str' objects>
```

See? That's its actual identity.

But we *can* call it over an existing string:

```
>>> 'foo'.isspace()
False
>>> '  foo    '.isspace()
False
>>> '   '.isspace()
True
>>> foo = '    '
>>> bar = '  blahblah  '
>>> foo.isspace()
True
>>> bar.isspace()
False
```

So you need to *assign* the thing you want to test first (you can reference it directly, but that will be annoying to read a few months from now when you want to maintain this code):

```
 def post(self):
    content = self.request.get('content')
    if content == '' or content.isspace():
        self.redirect('/error')
    else:
        wall_name = self.request.get('wall_name',DEFAULT_WALL)
        comment_container = CommentContainer(parent = wall_key(wall_name))
        comment_container.name = self.request.get('name')
        comment_container.content = self.request.get('content')
        comment_container.put()
        self.redirect('/#comment_section')
```

Now we've saved the work you were throwing away and checked for blank comments.

One note, you could also call change the `if` check to this:

```
if self.request.get('content') == '' or content.isspace(self.request.get('content')):
```

But again, I find this less obvious and clear.

Comment: Thank you so much, can you please give me an example with the strip( ) method

Answer (score 0):

`str.isspace()` is a method, so you would probably want to use:

```
elif str.isspace(comment_container.content):
```

or

```
elif isspace(comment_container.content.isspace():
```